# Drupal 8: How to change content in block in a custom module

Tags: drupal-8

I have a requirement to change the content in the block using custom module. Appreciate if anyone can suggest some pointers, examples or already existing custom modules for this purpose. Thanks

Comment: What is the type of that block? Block from view or custom block?

Comment: It is a view block

Comment: I tried to customize as below but it only works for few blocks for other blocks it errors out #markup returns null    function yourmodule_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) 

{
  if ($block->getBaseId() === 'system_powered_by_block') {
    $build['#pre_render'][] = '_yourmodule_block_poweredby_prerender';
  }
}

function _yourmodule_block_poweredby_prerender(array $build) {
    $build['content']['#markup'] = Markup::create('Your text');
    return $build;
}